# Collision detection with opengl es and android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 2d, collision-detection

I have been following the tutorials at http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/01/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-iii-%E2%80%93-transformations/ and I was wondering how I would go about implementing some 2d collision detection. I currently have 2 objects displayed on screen (1 of which is movable). How would I check if these objects intersect before I apply the movement?